# SphinxSE distinct empty result

Tags: distinct, sphinx

I run this query in sphinx se console:

```
SELECT @distinct FROM all_ips GROUP BY ip1;
```

I get this result:

```
+------+--------+
| id   | weight |
+------+--------+
|    1 |      1 |
|    2 |      1 |
|    3 |      1 |
|    9 |      1 |
|   15 |      1 |
|   16 |      1 |
|   17 |      1 |
|   20 |      1 |
|   21 |      1 |
|   25 |      1 |
|   26 |      1 |
|   27 |      1 |
|   31 |      1 |
|   32 |      1 |
|   38 |      1 |
|   39 |      1 |
|   40 |      1 |
|   46 |      1 |
|   50 |      1 |
|   51 |      1 |
+------+--------+
20 rows in set (0.57 sec)
```

How can i get number of unique values? Why @distinct column doesn't show up in results?

Answer (score 1):

1) I dont think that is sphinxSE - do you really mean sphinxQL? That looks more like sphinxQL.

2) Distinct of what column? You need to sell sphinx what attribute you want to count the distinct values in. In sphinxQL use COUNT(DISTINCT column_name)

Answer (score 1):

You will require simple SQL statement for getting count. Something like this

```
SELECT count(ip1),ip1 
FROM all_ips 
GROUP BY ip1;
```